# What does this expression do?

Tags: bitwise-operators, logical-operators

Is there any interpretation of this expression in the decimal system? In other words, is it an efficient implementation of calculation using the logical operation in place of arithmetic operation?

1) A number N plus a hexadecimal, i.e. (N+0x7f)
2) take the bitwise AND with the bitwise NOT of the same hexadecimal.

(N+0x7f) & (~0x7f)?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? And do you mean "i.e" (so it's always 0x7f) or "e.g" (and you want to know what it does for any hex value)? And how many bits is N? 16, 32...

Comment: Just 0x7f, thanks. 32 bits in N

Comment: Figured it out :-) it is changing N to the closest multiple of 0x7F which is greater than N.

Answer (score 1):

It is changing N to the closest multiple of 0x7F which is greater than N.